# Clicking on errors does nothing after editing outside of visual studio (VS2005)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm editing my C++ source code itself in sublime text 2 and compiling and debugging in Visual Studio 2005. I've noticed that after building, getting some errors, editing the source code in sublime, and reloading the changed text files in VS, that clicking on a specific error no longer takes me to the correct line in the source file. This is a bit annoying, and I was wondering if there was any easy way to fix this. Thanks in advance.